# Get custom message of raised error in trigger

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, raiseerror

I am working on a C# project with Entity Framework Core 5. I have a trigger which raises an error:

```sql
RAISERROR ('Conflict column bla bla bla.', 10, 1)
```

In the debug I see following:

[image]

How can I get the custom message?

Comment: According to SQL Server docs you should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`. Maybe it also bubbles up the exception message (no experience with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Gert Arnold, using `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR` fixed the problem:

```sql
THROW 5100, `Conflict column bla bla bla.', 1
```